# Collapse all when show one (different divs)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I'm using https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/collapse/

How can I collapse all elements when and show only one? It works on the same div, but if I divide the content into two divs, it doesn't.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">

  <div class="main-content mr-auto col-md-5 col-xl-4 p-5 mb-3">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content col-md-6 col-xl-7 p-5 mb-3">
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        pariat
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
       cliche
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

landfill text, landfill text, landfill text, landfill text, landfill text, landfill text

Comment: Can you post a fiddle and explain in details what happens and do you exactly want to happen?

Comment: Run snippet, I have buttons on one div and collapsible on other, when i show one, all of them don't hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## YOu can try this

Add below code in your template or in your custom js file.

```
 jQuery('div#accordionExample button').click(function(){
  jQuery('.main-content .collapse').removeClass('show');
 });
```

Here are codepane link: https://codepen.io/ronymaha/pen/NogbWd

Comment: Works, but if u click fast on button 3 and after on button 2 dont works

Comment: I think, you should add tab not accordion. So you can try this: https://codepen.io/ronymaha/pen/NogbWd

Comment: oh, ty, i didnt know that tab exist

Comment: and using bootstrap how can i do that tab-content height does not depend on the height of the nav-tabs div, but not using a fixed height, i want that tab-contend height depends of him own content